# Swift delete tableViewCell from popUp

Tags: swift, uitableview, delete-row, uialertcontroller

I have a button in a tableview cell that brings a Alert view. This alertView has the option to delete that cell. I cannot find anything on deleting a cell from another location than the edit or swipe options. Any tips please?

Comment: You could try implementing a delegate pattern, but without any examples of your code it is very difficult to help you. You may want to consider adding a minimal working example. @SashaZ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that you also want to animate that process.

```
  self.data.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
  self.tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Fade)
```

You first need to delete the data for that cell out of your array that you use for the tableView. Then you can delete a row on a specific NSIndexPath.

Comment: Thank you this was the correct method inside a AlertView. The tricky part was sharing what the indexPath.row was.